# Displaying percentage in Y-axis of Highcharts column chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart very similar to this one [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/).
I want to display percentage on the Y-axis and not the count.Count should be displayed on top of each bar.
I do not want to calculate percentage on server side.I want to acheive it through count values.
Please help

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Y axis to be a percentage of what?  The largest value as 100% and the rest as a percentage of that?

Comment: similar to stacked cloumn chart  with percent [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) but bar should not be stacked

Comment: Is that the same link as above?  If you want to change the stacking, see this http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.stacking, otherwise stop being confusing.

Comment: sorry for the confusion this is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-percent/).Instead of stacked(with percent) bars , i want it to be column chart with % values in Y-axis.

Answer (score 31):

You could do this:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    format: '{value}%'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is what I did:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
       return this.value+"%";
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: yaxis should be yAxis

Answer (score 9):

You can use formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter and add symbol to your label.

Answer (score 6):

what I did is:

```
yAxis: {min: 0, max:100,tickInterval: 25,
              title: {
                  text: "title"
              },
              labels: {
                  format: '{value}%',
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this in plot options,

plotOptions: {
      column: {
             stacking:'percent',
             pointPadding: 0.2,
             borderWidth: 0
            }
        },