# Plot percentages on y-axis with rhighcharts?

Tags: r, highcharts

Is it possible to tell `rhighcharts` that the y-axis should be percentages? For example:

```
library("highcharter")

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Some title") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = c("A", "Same", "B")) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(0.05,  0.26,  0.69),
                name = NULL)
```

Should be 5%, 26%, and 69%

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246187/displaying-percentage-in-y-axis-of-highcharts-column-chart with https://dantonnoriega.github.io/ultinomics.org/2017/04/05/thinking-in-highcharter---how-to-build-any-highcharts-plot-in-r.html

Comment: By default, highcharts does not support conversion from regular numbers to percentage. You can use the ["stacking" percent](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stacking) option only or transform your data to percent value (in the preprocessing).

Answer (score 6):

```
hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value}%")) %>%
```