# Highcharts X-axis and y-axis

Tags: reactjs, react-highcharts

I am using react-high-charts-official and I need to change the x-axis to a string values and y-axis to example: 1%, 2%, 3%. How do i achieve that? Also the bar graph tip should be round.

Comment: I have used the code below so far: chartOptions: {
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        },

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying percentage in Y-axis of Highcharts column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246187/displaying-percentage-in-y-axis-of-highcharts-column-chart)

Answer (score 0):

You can use axis label formatter.
Reference: [api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels.formatter)

```
 yAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      return this.value + ' units';
    }
  },
 }
```